# Elasticsearch container returns malformed http status response

Tags: docker, go, elasticsearch

I'm using the official `go-elasticsearch 7.x` api from golang to query an elasticsearch container:

I keep getting this response when I try to index some documents (after connecting successfully)

`Error getting response: net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: malformed HTTP status code "is"`

From what I can tell my request to index the document seems normal and it appears as though the error is coming from within the container? I've tried different TLS configurations, including no tls configuration at all and I still get the same response.

No error gets returns when I call `elasticClient.Info()` which it's connected to the client successfully

## golang:

```golang
var err error
    cfg := elasticsearch.Config{
        Addresses: []string{
            "http://elasticsearch:9200",
            "http://elasticsearch:9300",
        },
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
                Renegotiation: tls.RenegotiateOnceAsClient,
                Certificates:  []tls.Certificate{cer},
            },
        },
    }
    elasticClient, err = elasticsearch.NewClient(cfg)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
```

```golang
val, err := json.Marshal(&load)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error marshalling load, %v", err)
    }
    log.Printf("|| %s ||", string(val))
    req := esapi.IndexRequest{
        Index:      "load",
        DocumentID: strconv.Itoa(int(load.Id)),
        Body:       strings.NewReader(string(val)),
        Refresh:    "true",
    }
    info, err := elasticClient.Info()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    log.Println(info)
    // Perform the request with the client.
    res, err := req.Do(context.Background(), elasticClient)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error getting response: %s", err.Error())
    }
    if res.IsError() {
        log.Printf("[%s] Error indexing document ID=%s", res.Status(), strconv.Itoa(int(load.Id)))
    } else {

        // Deserialize the response into a map.
        var r map[string]interface{}
        if err := json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&r); err != nil {
            log.Printf("Error parsing the response body: %s", err)
        } else {
            // Print the response status and indexed document version.
            log.Printf("[%s] %s; version=%d", res.Status(), r["result"], int(r["_version"].(float64)))
        }
    }
    return nil
```

## typical json to index

`string(val)` in `IndexRequest`

```
{"deliverydate":"2019-08-28T13:00:00-04:00","temperature":"34",
"firstname":"****","loaddate":"2019-08-26T13:00:00-04:00","id":"188244","weight":"41918","totalcust":"2609","ponumber":"******","tsize":"53 ft","phone":"*******","equipment":"***","ext":"****","lastname":"****","pzip":"****",
"pcity":"****","pstate":"****","dzip":"22153","dcity":"*****","dstate":"****",
"locations":{"1":{"lat":44.260059,"long":-72.575387},"2":{"lat":38.748411,"long":-77.234767},"3":{},"4":{"lat":39.192978,"long":-76.7238},"5":{"lat":38.694281,"long":-75.772155},"6":{"lat":39.149275,"long":-76.775249},"7":{"lat":39.606779,"long":-75.833272}},"stopTypes":{"1":"P","2":"D","3":"D","4":"D","5":"D","6":"D","7":"D"}}
```

## docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  redis_server:
    image: "redis"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  lambda_server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:50051"
    depends_on:
      - redis_server
      - elasticsearch
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.3.1
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"      
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - http.cors.enabled=true
      - http.cors.allow-origin=*
```

## Edit 1:

Just tried wrapping the request in a loop to see if something changes and it appears to produce something more useful:

`lambda_server_1  | 2019/08/24 17:25:59 [400 Bad Request] Error indexing document ID=188243
lambda_server_1  | 2019/08/24 17:25:59 [400 Bad Request] Error indexing document ID=189265`

It appears it's a poorly formed request? Despite following the [example](https://github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/blob/master/_examples/main.go) exactly.

### edited code:

```golang
func cacheLoadsToSearch() {
    data := redisClient.Scan(0, "*", totalNewLoads).Iterator()
    accessedKeys := map[string]bool{}
    for data.Next() {
        id := data.Val()
        if accessedKeys[id] {
            continue //continue to next iteration of loop, Scan cursor may return duplicate results
        } else {
            accessedKeys[id] = true
        }
        loadItem, err := readFromRedis(id)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Error reading from redis cache, %v", err)
        }
        wg.Add(1)
        pushToElasticSearch(loadItem)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}

func pushToElasticSearch(load *lambdapb.Load) error {
    val, err := json.Marshal(&load)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error marshalling load, %v", err)
    }
    log.Printf("|| %s ||", string(val))
    req := esapi.IndexRequest{
        Index:      "load",
        DocumentID: strconv.Itoa(int(load.Id)),
        Body:       strings.NewReader(string(val)),
        Refresh:    "true",
    }
    info, err := elasticClient.Info()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    log.Println(info)
    // Perform the request with the client.
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for {
            res, err := req.Do(context.Background(), elasticClient)
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("Error getting response fron indexRequest: %s", err.Error())
                time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
                continue
            }
            if res.IsError() {
                log.Printf("[%s] Error indexing document ID=%s", res.Status(), strconv.Itoa(int(load.Id)))
                time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
                continue
            } else {

                // Deserialize the response into a map.
                var r map[string]interface{}
                if err := json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&r); err != nil {
                    log.Printf("Error parsing the response body: %s", err)
                } else {
                    // Print the response status and indexed document version.
                    log.Printf("[%s] %s; version=%d", res.Status(), r["result"], int(r["_version"].(float64)))
                }
                break
            }
        }
    }()
    return nil
}
```

I also edited the setup function

```golang
func setupElasticSearch() error {
    var err error
    cfg := elasticsearch.Config{
        Addresses: []string{
            "http://elasticsearch:9200",
            "http://elasticsearch:9300",
        },
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
                Renegotiation: tls.RenegotiateOnceAsClient,
                Certificates:  []tls.Certificate{cer},
            },
        },
    }
    elasticClient, err = elasticsearch.NewClient(cfg)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    done := make(chan int)
    go func(done chan<- int) {
        for {
            res, err := elasticClient.Indices.Create("load")
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("Malformed response to create index: %s", err)
                time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
                continue
            }
            if res.IsError() {
                log.Printf("Cannot create index: %s", res)
                time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
                continue
            }
            log.Print("Successfully created index")
            break
        }
        done <- 1
    }(done)
    <-done
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Just an idea, because I don't know the elasticsearch api: you're setting up tls but using http:// urls, shouldn't that be https://?

Comment: @bserdar changing it to https outputted a different error to do with tls, it won't even connect to the client

Comment: As I said, I'm not familiar with the elastic api, so what you had might be the right way. It was just an idea...

Comment: @bserdar no problem! thank you for the advice anyway!

Comment: @AdrianCoutsoftides just a question: if you're already having the data in Redis why don't you just use RediSearch to query it?

Comment: @GuyKorland This is because the client has a large datastore, as such I had to develop a multi-temperature storage solution, redis is being used as hot storage, and elastic search as warm storage because when the system goes into the production objects not residing within the redis cache will also need to be queried